# SASS Specificity hierarchy

Tags: jquery, css, sass

Why will the below Div not appear on button click?
How can I resolve it, without using !important in class two?
I don't want to use removeClass as well.

```js
function run(){
   $('.one').addClass('two');
}
```

```css
.base{
  background-color:#FF0000;
  & .one{
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    
    color:#FFF;
 }
 }
.two{
  opacity:1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="base">
    <div class="one">
       Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
<button click="run()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/o0dc5p45/

Comment: Did you look at the compiled CSS?  Is it what you expected?

Comment: Yes. I am giving a replica of my exact use case. 
There is a problem with the opacity not being changed to 1. I am using SASS.

Comment: That does not answer my question:  is the compiled CSS what you expected it to be?

Comment: Yes. 
The class goes like:
.base{
 background-color :#FF0000;
}
.base .one{
   opacity:0;
   display:block;
   color:#FFF;
}
.two{
  opacity:1;
}

Answer (score 0):

The html should be onclick not click

```js
function run(){
   $('.one').addClass('two');
}
```

```css
.one{
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
  background-color:#FF0;
  color:#FFF;
 }

.two{
  opacity:1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  Hello World!
</div>

<button onclick="run()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: My bad for the typo. Even then it doesn't work in my use case. Let me try posting it different.

Comment: Funny! I am not able to do the same thing in an Ember JS application!
It works good if I do it with pure jquery.

Comment: Modified the question, the problem was with SASS hierarchy.